Access Denied for MySQL User 'root' in Laravel
I am encountering an error when trying to connect to my MySQL database in a Laravel application. The error message is:
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

My .env Configuration:
Here are the relevant parts of my .env file:
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=multivendor_ecommerce
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=0000

Context:

I did not set a password for my MySQL user, but I am trying to use 0000 as the password.
I have checked the MySQL user privileges and am unsure if they are set correctly.

Questions:

How can I resolve the access denied error?
Should I set a password for the root user, and if so, how do I do that?
Are there any best practices for managing database users in Laravel?

Additional Information:

My MySQL server is running locally.
I have tried connecting to MySQL using the command line with the same credentials.


You can login to MySQL and then change password with ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root-password';
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/default-privileges.html

Make the password the string: "" and see

Thanks, but I'd like to set my password. How can I do that?

SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('mypass');
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
